# extract number from string excel

Tags: excel

I have a string in Excel which is of the following format:

```
Total Work15 / 10015.00%G
Total Work364 / 1000364.00%Y
Total Work13 / 4552.86%B
```

Its a bizarre format, but it's being generated by a system I have no control over.

I'm interested in extracting the number 15 after the word "work". At present I am using this:

```
=MID(A2,11,FIND(" ",A2,11)-11)
```

and that return "15 " but appears to have a space at the end and I can't therefore do anything with the number as an int.

Can someone help so I only end up with the int and not with the trailing space?

Comment: note, the number I'm interested in may be more than 2 digits long, but the point being its between "k" and the second " "

Comment: can you show more rows that you want to extract? so we can understand the pattern better?

Comment: There is no space at the end, but it's a text. Add `*1` at the end to convert to int.

Comment: i tried that to be honest, but get a #value error

Comment: @Balinti updated with some more examples...

Comment: Change the length of your mid function to be -12, instead of -11. Then convert to value with the VALUE function.

Comment: Check what does `=CODE(MID(A2,13,1))` return with your first string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just a trailing space in this case that's causing it to not act like a number - its that it is pulled from a string - meaning that Excel automatically guesses its a string value.

To fix it in this formula - you could just do :

```
=VALUE(MID(A2,11,FIND(" ",A2,11)-11))
```

In general however, you might find that pulling numbers from strings is better using a vba Regex function

Comment: I've tested the code and that string - and strangely it works absolutely find for me. What are you trying to do with the string? I added/multiplied it to text and it worked as expected

Comment: it must be to do with the data source, your answer works for me if I recreate it not using the source data. very weird.

Comment: You could try - =VALUE(MID(CLEAN(TRIM(A2)),11,FIND(" ",A2,11)-11))
That will often help with unusual formatting bugs

Comment: No problem, it could be something like a trailing space - or possibly a funny encoding issue somewhere along the lines. Trim removes double spaces and Clean removes non-printables. Both very useful functions to remember

Comment: yeh, looks like it was clean that was doing the trick. Definitely noted for next time. Thanks!