# How to extract specific numbers from string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Was wondering if there was a way to extract the numbers out of the middle text. For example below, for AG5612, is there a way to extract 5612 using a formula? I'm having a difficult time with LEFT, RIGHT, and MID because the middle text differs in length. Much appreciated.

```
Column A    
948321 AG5612 CA    
932 SA15 SA    
98223 WS8 FS
```

Comment: is it always the second text?

Comment: And are the numbers always to the right of the text in that group?

Comment: How about using a regular expression, for instance: `=RegExExtract(".*(P[0-9a-z]+).*";A1;"$1")`

Comment: It is always the second text. Yes always to the right. I've tried =MID(A2,SEARCH(B2,D2)+2,4) but due to the dynamic length of the middle text, I can't find a solution. I've created a separate column (B) and listed out the two letters to start at using SEARCH. I'm having it return 4 characters but the issue with that is, for example, WS8, it'll return 8 FS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract number from string excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332425/extract-number-from-string-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))),1E+99)),FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","{{{",2))-MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))),1E+99))-FIND(" ",A1))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Amazing. This works. One more question - let's say there was a space between SA and 15, or SA 15, but there were not spaces in the others.  How could I get that to work?

Comment: You would need another formula, totally different,  If this gets 98% of them then you will need to deal with the others manually.

Comment: {=IF(ISTEXT(D2),D2,--MID(D2,FIND(" ",D2)+MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},MID(D2,FIND(" ",D2)+1,LEN(D2))),1E+99)),FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE(D2," ","{{{",2))-MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},MID(D2,FIND(" ",D2)+1,LEN(D2))),1E+99))-FIND(" ",D2)))}   would you know why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This formula will find the position where the numbers begin:
`=MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))`

Enter that in a column and name the header `Position`.
Then, in another column, use this formula to extract just the numbers:

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-position+1)`

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but here is a shortened, non-array formula that will always get the number after the first space (regardless of how many spaces are between the first space and the number):

```
=LOOKUP(2^999,--MID(A1,MAX(INDEX(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1))),0),))+FIND(" ",A1)-ROW($1:$99)+1,ROW($1:$99)))
```

[image]